# Debug a C# dll called from a native dll

Tags: debugging, dll

I have a managed C# dll (call it C) which is consumed by another (native) dll.
The calling dll (call it B) is an Autocad plug-in.
I can't find a way to debug into C; I can of course debug into B.

Comment: Right-click the C# project in the Solution Explorer window, click "Set as StartUp Project".  Project > Properties > Debug tab, set the path to acad.  Set breakpoints in the code you need to debug and press F5.

Comment: Thanks, but I knew that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it (not my solution):
As we're trying to debug a .NET assembly, the problem has to do with the framework:
It seems that Acad is configured (acad.exe.config) for NET 4.0, so when the VS2008 debugger, which knows nothing above NET 3.5 sees the NET 4.0 it simply refuses to go on, with a cryptic message about debugger incompatibility with the debuggee. 
The solution (see https://civilizeddevelopment.typepad.com/civilized-development/2011/04/developing-applications-for-autocad-civil-3d-2012.html) is to modify the Acad config file, and all works fine.